# How can I find my comment on a Google+ post when no one has commented after me?

Tags: google-plus, comments

Let's say you make a comment on a Google+ post and someone comments on the post after you.  You'll receive notifications with links back to the post.  Even if you have disabled notifications, you can still find the post you commented on by navigating to https://plus.google.com/notifications/otherposts via Notifications -> More -> Posts by others.

If you make a comment on a post and **no one comments after you**, however, you may well have trouble ever finding that post again.  You'll receive no notifications (there's really nothing to notify you about), and I'm not aware of any URL you can visit to see those comments you've made **when no one has yet commented after you**.  Is there such a URL?

Sorry for all the emphasis, but I've [already asked](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/d/topic/google-plus-discuss/5dv5lDUfpmI/discussion) about this on the google-plus-discuss list, and multiple people have mentioned notifications, which are no help **when no one comments after you**.

I really think this deserves an entry on the [Google+ Known Issues](http://www.google.com/support/profiles/bin/static.py?page=known_issues.cs) page.  I'm less inclined to put any thought into comments if I know I may never see them again.

Comment: They've got a couple hundred enhancements in the pipeline, and some of the recent ones have come as a result of user feedback. I strongly suggest that you use the "Feedback" option to request this improvement.

Comment: A full list is available here: https://plus.google.com/apps/activities/comments

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Ronnie Bincer offers a technique for finding your comments](https://plus.google.com/108210288375340023376/posts/KWBg8ETMCCu):

> Use Google Plus SEARCH in a special way and you can find your comments (and other people's shares of your stuff, etc.)
>
> **Use this technique to find your comments...**
>
> *Enter a Google Plus search like this:*
>
> "Ronnie Bincer" -inurl:108210288375340023376
>
> Where the name in quotes is **Your Google Plus name** and the number after the '-inurl:' text is **Your Profile ID**.
>
> You can find your profile ID number by going to your 'Profile' area and snagging it from within the URL up top.

Comment: This works quite well and you can even save the search (which you can find again under "Explore"). I'm going to delete my answer from 2012-02-26 which says: "After I asked this question, Google introduced search within Google+. I suppose search is your best hope of finding your comment on a Google+ post when no one has commented after you."

Comment: I'm glad this worked out for you.

Comment: But would it work for someone with a common name like John Smith?

Comment: Does this still work? Any easier way?

Answer (score 1):

You are wanting something like Facebook where it posts to your profile that "'so-and-so' posted on 'so-and-so2's wall." right?

Well I'm sorry to say on Google+ there is no feature that consolidates all the places you've posted. You would have to go find that post again.

However, Google+, if you remember, is only a few weeks old and still in beta. That means you are lucky enough to be able to [make a suggestion](http://www.google.com/intl/en/+/learnmore/forum/) and probably be heard over at the dev team. Click the "Options" icon, then "Send Feedback".

Comment: Yeah, but we don't want them making it so that all the comments you ever make appear on your profile like on Facebook... -_-

Answer (score 0):

If you have notifications set up to send Google+ posts to your email, you can search there.

I had it where I had a post I couldn't locate (since no one had commented after me and I got no notifications) so I thought of a keyword that I thought might have been in the post and search in my Gmail message and found it.

This is a tricky issue where the G+ search may show useless results if you don't search for the right keyword or you have no other way to search the posts/comments.

Comment: I guess that's okay if you keep your notification messages around and you've already got it set up to send the notifications in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

Click "Notifications" on the left of your G+ page then the "More" in the top center of the page then "Posts by others".

Comment: And how does that help if no one comments afterwards in order to trigger the notification?