# How to see all of my Google Plus past interactions in one place?

Tags: google-plus

I'd like to know how to see all of my Google Plus past interactions in one single place.
If I go to the "Posts" page I see some past posts I've made. But it seems that some posts are missing and it also doesn't show other interactions such as +1s and comments I did to other peoples's posts.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that there *is* a place to see all of your G+ activity.

Obviously the "[Posts](https://plus.google.com/me/posts)" section of your profile shows all of the posts that you have made.

Another spot is the recently added "[Mentions](https://plus.google.com/stream/mentions)". It shows posts where your name has been used via `+Your Name`.

Your [+1s](https://plus.google.com/me/plusones) show the various links around the web you've "plus oned".

[Reviews](https://plus.google.com/me/reviews) shows the places on Google Maps (and the former Google Local) that you've applied star ratings to.

The [Activity Log](https://plus.google.com/apps/activities) available under "Settings" would appear to be the right spot, but from what I can see there's only +1s on posts and pages.

As seen on this other question ([How can I find my comment on a Google+ post when no one has commented after me?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/17980/354)) it's not very easy to see comments you've made long after you've made them.

So, aside from doing a search on your name, I don't know that there's a way to see all of your interactions. This is obviously not helpful if you share a name with someone who is active at all.